# How can I add event listener to just button element

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code.

```
<button id ="id"><span>fire!</span></button>
<script>
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click',e=>{
    console.log(e.target)
}) 
</script>
```

then we can find simple button in DOM.
Once I click button, script returns

```
<span>fire<\span>
```

or

```
<button id="id"> ...</button>
```

.

How can I add event listener to just button element?

Comment: Are you saying, you do not want to fire, if a user clicks on the span text fire? only the button wrapping it?

Comment: Please explain more properly

Comment: @Spangle  Yes. only button event

Comment: <button id ="id" style="padding:30px"><span 
   style="border:solid">

this should be good. in the span element and out of the span element, event.target capture differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as one of the options... You can use the `currentTarget`.

In your case, it will be like this:

```js
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', e=> {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<button id ="id"><span>fire!</span></button>
```

Comment: sorry for newbie 

Comment: @misohagi, no problem :)